# How to solve this first-order ODE $\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{y^6-2x^2}{2x^2y+2y^3-y}$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

solve this ODE equation

> $$\dfrac{dy}{dx}=\dfrac{y^6-2x^2}{2x^2y+2y^3-y}$$

My try:

> $$\dfrac{y~dy}{dx}=\dfrac{y^6-2x^2}{2x^2+2y^2-1}$$
>   let
>   $$u=y^2$$
>   then
>   $$\dfrac{du}{dx}=\dfrac{2u^3-4x^2}{2x^2+2u-1}$$

then I can't work. Thank you, this problem is from ODE equation excise book,

[image]

and this book only take this answer:

$$(y^3-3x)^7(y^3+2x)^3=cx^{15}$$

Comment: hmm... if we find $y'(x)$ from the answer, it does not appear that it will match the original equation: $7\ln(y^3-3x)+3\ln(y^3+2x)=15\ln x +\mbox{conts }\Longrightarrow y'=\frac{y^6-2x^2}{x^2y^2+2xy^5}$. Might there be a typo ?

Answer (score 0):

You did it correctly.

Now for $\dfrac{du}{dx}=\dfrac{2u^3-4x^2}{2x^2+2u-1}$ ,

$(2u+2x^2-1)\dfrac{du}{dx}=2u^3-4x^2$

Let $v=u+x^2-\dfrac{1}{2}$ ,

Then $u=v-x^2+\dfrac{1}{2}$

$\dfrac{du}{dx}=\dfrac{dv}{dx}-2x$

$\therefore2v\left(\dfrac{dv}{dx}-2x\right)=2\left(v-x^2+\dfrac{1}{2}\right)^3-4x^2$

$2v\dfrac{dv}{dx}-4xv=2v^3-6\left(x^2-\dfrac{1}{2}\right)v^2+6\left(x^2-\dfrac{1}{2}\right)^2v-2\left(x^2-\dfrac{1}{2}\right)^3-4x^2$

$2v\dfrac{dv}{dx}=2v^3-6\left(x^2-\dfrac{1}{2}\right)v^2+\left(6\left(x^2-\dfrac{1}{2}\right)^2+4x\right)v-2\left(x^2-\dfrac{1}{2}\right)^3-4x^2$

$v\dfrac{dv}{dx}=v^3-3\left(x^2-\dfrac{1}{2}\right)v^2+\left(3\left(x^2-\dfrac{1}{2}\right)^2+2x\right)v-\left(x^2-\dfrac{1}{2}\right)^3-2x^2$

This belongs to an Abel equation of the second kind.

In fact all Abel equation of the second kind can be transformed into Abel equation of the first kind.

Let $v=\dfrac{1}{w}$ ,

Then $\dfrac{dv}{dx}=-\dfrac{1}{w^2}\dfrac{dw}{dx}$

$\therefore-\dfrac{1}{w^3}\dfrac{dw}{dx}=\dfrac{1}{w^3}-3\left(x^2-\dfrac{1}{2}\right)\dfrac{1}{w^2}+\left(3\left(x^2-\dfrac{1}{2}\right)^2+2x\right)\dfrac{1}{w}-\left(x^2-\dfrac{1}{2}\right)^3-2x^2$

$\dfrac{dw}{dx}=\left(\left(x^2-\dfrac{1}{2}\right)^3+2x^2\right)w^3-\left(3\left(x^2-\dfrac{1}{2}\right)^2+2x\right)w^2+3\left(x^2-\dfrac{1}{2}\right)w-1$

Please follow the method in http://www.hindawi.com/journals/ijmms/2011/387429/#sec2